# Can I add data members/variables to a struct from outside its definition in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, struct

There is a struct already defined in C++. I need to add more data members/variables as that class's object's attributes. Can it be done? If yes, then how?

Comment: Why can't you just change the struct?

Comment: If you need objects to be dynamic at runtime, you could add an `std::map<std::string, std::variant<...>>` member.

Comment: I'm writing code for a problem on a coding platform where the code for the original struct is not available. @RetiredNinja

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to do? What is the problem, to which adding members to the struct is the proposed solution?

Comment: _"I need to add more data members/variables as that class's object's attributes. Can it be done?"_ No, you can't change a struct/class. But you tagged this question with _"inheritance"_ Of course, you can derive a class and change the derived class.

Comment: If the code of the original `struct` is not available. How you expect to modify it. This is not how C++ works. C++ must see all definitions at compile time and a definition must also be unique.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do:

```cpp
class
non_writable
{
        int private_member;
        int private_function (int, int);
    protected:
        char protected_member;
        char protected_function (char, char);
    public:
        double public_member;
        double public_function (double, double);
};

class
my_class : public non_writable
{
    public:
        double introduced_variable;
        double introduced_function (double, double);
}
```

The downfall to this method is that private members (i.e. `private_variable`, `private_function`) will not be inherited to `my_class`.

Comment: they will be inherited, they just won't be visible from `my_class`